# In regex parse of sumo logic, how can I allow for and throw away wildcards?

Tags: regex, sumologic

Consider an access log of a REST API, you will see lines (simplified) that looks like this:

```
2017-01-01T12:12:41Z "GET /api/posts" HTTP/1.1 200 "-"
2017-01-01T12:12:42Z "GET /api/posts/56/comments" HTTP/1.1 200 "-"
2017-01-01T12:12:42Z "GET /api/posts" HTTP/1.1 200 "-"
2017-01-01T12:12:56Z "POST /api/posts" HTTP/1.1 202 "Safari"
2017-01-01T12:12:58Z "GET /api/posts/134/comments" HTTP/1.1 200 "-"
```

To parse that you could write something like :

```
_collector=access.log | regex parse "(?<method>[A-Z]+) /api/(?<path>[\w\d\/]+) HTTP"
```

This would extract METHOD and PATH form the log lines, BUT you would see these unique values:

- GET posts
- POST posts
- GET posts/56/comments
- GET posts/134/comments

I wish to throw away all the dynamic parts of the url, so I could find the following instead:

- GET posts
- POST posts
- GET posts/{id}/comments

I could figure out this in a search and replace regex easily enough, but is it even possible in Sumologic?

Comment: Is the ID consistently the second resource in the URL? For example, "/api/posts/56/comments" or "/api/posts/56/shares", or "/api/users/72". You know what I mean? If so, why not parse out each resource of the URL, then you can keep or toss whatever you want (parent resource, id, child resource, etc.). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though...

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to see in the Sumo Logic output?